# Javascript Confirmation On if..else.. condition

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, confirm

I have to show confirmation dialogue on particular condition.And then proceed according to YES or No clicked.I tried with the following.

In aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowConfirmation() {
    if (confirm("Employee Introduced already.Continue?") == true) {
      document.getElementById("hdn_empname").value = 1;
    }
  }

</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_empname" runat="server" />
```

in cs:

```
  if (reader2.HasRows)
    {  
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showAl", "ShowConfirmation();", true);
    }
    else
    {
        hdn_empname.Value ="1";
    }

    if ((hdn_empname.Value)=="1")
    {
       //some code to execute
    }
```

But `hdn_empname` shows `value=""` while debuging.

Can anyone help me doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your break point? If reader2.HasRows returns true your javascript will be registered. But it set the value on client and you get the result after postback.

Comment: The above code(in question) is under button click. and I have set breakpoint in button click.

Comment: So as i explained above the script is registered to client and the value will be eq 1 in the next post back. I think it is better that you set the ShowConfirmation function on onClientClick of you button.

Comment: Ok.. But i need it the confimation only on particular condition

Comment: May be the condition can be handled in ShowConfirmation function.But if you need to handle the condition in server side you can not handle it by this way. I suggest you using ajax call for handling the condition and showing confirm modal.

Answer (score 2):

Try it
 You need to `ClientID`

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdn_empname.ClientID%>').value = 1;
```

I found out your main problems

> The hidden field values will assign after the if condition call.

**Edit :**

So, You need to call your logic's in javascript side using ajax

```
if (confirm("Employee Introduced already.Continue?") == true) {

//some code to execute
    }
```

Comment: So where do I assign the values?

Comment: Alborz already said theis:  it is better that you set the ShowConfirmation function on onClientClick of you button

Answer (score 1):

`hdn_empname` is server controls Id which is different from client sided id, to get client sided id you need to use ClientID

try this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdn_empname.ClientID%>').value = "1";
```

You dont need to compare

```
if (confirm("Employee Introduced already.Continue?") == true)
```

this will work:

```
if (confirm("Employee Introduced already.Continue?"))
```

Comment: No this did not wok for me